# previous most recent bigger element in array

Tags: algorithm

I try to solve the following problem. Given an array of real numbers `[7, 2, 4, 8, 1, 1, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1]` for every element I need to find most recent previous bigger element in the array.

For example there is nothing bigger then first element (7) so it has NaN. For the second element (2) 7 is bigger. So in the end the answer looks like:

`[NaN, 7, 7, NaN, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1]`. Of course I can just check all the previous elements for every element, but this is quadratic in terms of  the number of elements of the array.

My another approach was to maintain the sorted list of previous elements and then select the first element bigger then current. This sounds like a log linear to me (am not sure). Is there any better way to approach this problem?

Comment: sorting is `O(nlogn)` not `O(logn)`. I think `O(nlogn)` is the best approach.

Comment: @levi I thought that log linear is O(nlogn)

Comment: For each number, do you just need to find *some* previous number that was bigger, or does it have to be the *most recent* bigger number? In the first case, it would be easily doable in O(n)

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, do you want to compare the current and previous element and find the greatest from the 2 elements.

Comment: sorry @HugoRune I need to find most recent bigger element. I will update the answer.

Comment: You are looking for some kind of fibonacci series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
create a stack which is initially empty
for each number N in the array
{
    while the stack is not empty
    {
        if the top item on the stack T is greater than N
        {
            output T (leaving it on the stack)
            break
        }
        else
        {
            pop T off of the stack
        }
    }
    if the stack is empty
    {
        output NAN
    }
    push N onto the stack
}
```

Taking your sample array [7, 2, 4, 8, 1, 1, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1], here's how the algorithm would solve it.

```
stack           N             output  
-               7               NAN 
7               2               7
7 2             4               7
7 4             8               NAN
8               1               8
8 1             1               8
8 1             6               8
8 6             7               8
8 7             4               7
8 7 4           3               4
8 7 4 3         1               3
```

The theory is that the stack doesn't need to keep small numbers since they will never be part of the output. For example, in the sequence `7, 2, 4`, the 2 is not needed, because any number less than 2 will also be less than 4. Hence the stack only needs to keep the 7 and the 4.

**Complexity Analysis**

The time complexity of the algorithm can be shown to be *O(n)* as follows:

1. there are exactly `n` pushes (each number in the input array is
   pushed onto the stack once and only once)
2. there are at most `n` pops (once a number is popped from the stack,
   it is discarded)
3. there are at most `n` failed comparisons (since the number is popped
   and discarded after a failed comparison)
4. there are at most `n` successful comparisons (since the algorithm
   moves to the next number in the input array  after a successful
   comparison)
5. there are exactly `n` output operations (since the algorithm
   generates one output for each number in the input array)

Hence we conclude that the algorithm executes at most `5n` operations to complete the task, which is a time complexity of *O(n)*.

Comment: Wow, it looks so nice. Thank you. Will still need to understand how it works though.

Comment: You can argue your algorithm is linear since you have at most `n` pops and at each step you make `1 + (number of pops in step)` comparisons

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Yes, that's exactly right. I added a section to the answer to explain the time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

We can keep for each array element the index of the its most recent bigger element. When we process a new element x, we check the previous element y. If y is greater then we found what we want. If not, we check which is the index of the most recent bigger element of y. We continue until we find our needed element and its index. Using python:

```
a = [7, 2, 4, 8, 1, 1, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1]
idx, result = [], []
for i, v in enumerate(a, -1):
    while i >= 0 and v >= a[i]:
        i = idx[i]
    idx.append(i)
    result.append(a[i] if i >= 0 else None)
```

Result:

```
[None, 7, 7, None, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 4, 3]
```

The algorithm is linear. When an index `j` is unsuccessfully checked because we are looking for the most recent bigger element of index `i > j` then from now on `i` will point to a smaller index than `j` and `j` won't be checked again.

Comment: Sorry, I can not upvote your answer. Will do this when will have enough reputation. Really thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just define a variable 'current_largest' and iterate through your array from left to right? At each element, current largest is largest previous, and if the current element is larger, assign current_largest to the current element. Then move to the next element.

EDIT:
I just re-read your question and I may have misunderstood it. Do you want to find ALL larger previous elements?

EDIT2:
It seems to me like the current largest method will work. You just need to record current_largest before you assign it a new value. For example, in python:

```
current_largest = 0
for current_element in elements:
    print("Largest previous is "+current_largest)
    if(current_element>current_largest):
        current_largest = current_element
```

If you want an array of these, then just push the value to an array in place of the print statement.

Comment: I can not have the current largest, because I do not need to find the largest element. I need to find the previous biggest for every element. For example if in array [100, 2, 3, 10, 4, 9]. For example if I will be saving the biggest, then for element 9 I will get 100, but should have got 10.

Answer (score 0):

As per my best understanding of your question. Below is a solution.
Working Example : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/s6r4b350/)

```
 var item = document.getElementById("myButton");
item.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    var myItems = [7, 2, 4, 8, 1, 1, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1];
    var previousItem;
    var currentItem;
    var currentLargest;
    for (var i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++) {
        currentItem = myItems[i];
        if (i == 0) {
            previousItem = myItems[0];
            currentItem = myItems[0];
            myItems[i] = NaN;
        }
        else {
            if (currentItem < previousItem) {
                myItems[i] = previousItem;
                currentLargest = previousItem;
            }
            if (currentItem > currentLargest) {
                currentLargest = currentItem;
                myItems[i] = NaN;
            }
            else {
                myItems[i] = currentLargest;
            }
            previousItem = currentItem;
        }
    }
    var stringItems = myItems.join(",");
    document.getElementById("arrayAnswer").innerHTML = stringItems;
}
```

Comment: It does not look like a correct answer. I should have got something like this: `[NaN, 7, 7, NaN, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 4, 3, 1]`, whereas I see `[7, 7, NaN, NaN, 8, 1, NaN, NaN, 7, 4, 3]`